# Should I send an Authorization header with every HTTP request?

Tags: angular, rest, http, authentication, get

In an `Angular` web app, after the user is authenticated and authorized, `GET` requests are sent to fetch some database objects. This backend resource does not require Authorization headers/tokens to be sent along with the `HTTP` request in order to retrieve the data. My current `GET` requests work fine despite not using `HttpInterceptor` to append an Authorization header w/ bearer token.

Even though the server doesn't require a `bearer token` at the moment, is it best practice to include the bearer token with every `CRUD` request, regardless? What are some reasons why I may or may not want to do so?

My thoughts are that I’m surprised this backend resource doesn’t require bearer tokens. I briefly pondered getting ahead of the game and wiring up the httpInterceptor to send the bearer token before the backend was setup to receive them (future proofing the app in anticipation of backend implementing this?) but I figured this may do more harm than good.

Comment: No, you should definitely not preemptively send authentication to an endpoint that doesn't require it.

Comment: Thanks @Evert, that's what my gut was telling me. Can you explain why that would be bad?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need authentication then you do not need solutions like HttpInterceptor or session/bearer tokens.

There are many resources available on the web to learn this.

https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/what-is-bearer-token-and-how-it-works/

To answer this type of question in the future, I would start by typing your question into a search engine.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=why+use+a+bearer+token